# org.apache.predictionio#apache-predictionio-core_2.10_2.10;0.10.0-incubating: not found

Tags: scala, predictionio

I was trying to use universal recommender using predictionIO. I was using the template: template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation.
I have imported the file and while building the engine, I am getting an error:

```
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]     module not found: 
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] ==== local: tried
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]   /home/neron/.ivy2/local/io.prediction/core_2.10/0.12.0-incubating/ivys/ivy.xml
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] ==== public: tried
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/prediction/core_2.10/0.12.0-incubating/core_2.10-0.12.0-incubating.pom
```

and

```
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]     ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES     ::
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]     :: org.apache.predictionio#apache predictionio-core_2.10_2.10;0.10.0-incubating: not found
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn] 
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]     Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[INFO] [Engine$] [warn]    org.apache.predictionio:apache predictionio-core_2.10_2.10:0.10.0-incubating(/home/neron/Professional/PIO_Projects/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation/build.sbt#L9-31)


[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.predictionio#apache-predictionio-core_2.10_2.10;0.10.0-incubating: not found
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed 8 Dec, 2017 2:35:53 PM
```

In my .ivy2 folder, I have folders like:

```
/home/name/.ivy2/local/org.apache.predictionio/apache-predictionio-core_2.10/0.10.0-incubating/ivys/ivy.xml
```

instead of io.prediction/core/....

I tried changing the engine.sbt file with the path that I have, but still got the same error with the path I provided.

Is this because of any other error that I had done?

Answer (score 2):

Replace io.predictionio with org.apache.predictionio in your complete template.